# Get the port number from the process id in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get the port number for the running process in UNIX.

below command gives me process ID:

```
ps -ef | grep process_name

502   741   389   0 11:02AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep process_name
```

Can someone please help me on how to get the ports used by the process. Thanks!

Comment: `netstat -lptu | grep PID`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it doesn't work, I am getting netstat: tu: unknown or uninstrumented protocol ERROR. Please help!

Comment: It works for Linux. What UNIX is that? It would be more suitable for this page anyway: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's the PID of the `grep` process itself, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lsof` command to list ports in Mac OS X.

```
# This will list all the ports
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i LISTEN   

# This will list ports used by PID# <pid>
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i LISTEN | grep <pid>
```